# How to make an array of characters into an array of strings in Swift

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, character

Here is my code:

```
var myString:String = "abc"

var myStringArray = Array(myString)

myStringArray[0] = String("cow")
```

I turn the string "abc" into the array ["a","b","c"]. I then try to turn the first element into "cow" so that I have the array ["cow","b","c"]. But it doesn't let me do the last part (i.e. the third line) since the elements in the array are CHARACTERS not STRINGS (so I can't replace the character "a" with the string "cow").

So how do I overcome this? I assume I want to make it so the elements in ["a","b","c"] are interpreted in the program as strings (that are each one letter long), so that I can make the desired replacement. But how to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your new array's `map` method to convert the `Character` instances to `String`:

```
var myString:String = "abc"

var myStringArray = Array(myString).map { String($0) }

myStringArray[0] = String("cow")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myString:String = "abc"

var myStringArray = myString.characters.map{String($0)}

myStringArray[0] = String("cow")
```